# Combining two terms into a quadratic form

Tags: optimization, lasso, quadratic-form, constrained-optimization

I have an objective function defined by $ min_{Y_{t}} \hspace{2mm} ||X_{t} - Y_{t}D_{t}^{T}||_{F}^{2} + \lambda_{2}\sum_{i,j} w_{i,j}||\mathbf{y}_{i} - \mathbf{p}_{j}^{t}||_{2}^{2}$ where capital $T$ (above $D_{t}$) is matrix transpose operation. Subscript $t$ may be ignored as it was only for representation purpose.

Authors in https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7410639have commented that these two terms may be combined into a single quadratic term. Not sure how?

The form for the second term looks like $||YW-P||_{F}^{2}$ though not sure if I am correct. Kindly help.

Edits:

In the above optimization problem, the variable parameter is $Y_{t}$.

The matrices are denoted by capital letters while boldfaced small letters denote the vectors.

The dimensions of different variables are as follows:

$X_{t} \in \Re^{6985 \times 4096}$ where $6985$ and $4096$ represent number of test instances and dimensionality of the **feature** space respectively.

$Y_{t} \in \Re^{6985 \times 85}$ where where $6985$ and $85$ represent number of test instances and dimensionality of the **semantic** space respectively; $\mathbf{y}_{i}$ represents i-th row of $Y_{t}$

$P \in \Re^{10 \times 85}$ where $10$ and $85$ represent number of test classes and dimensionality of the **semantic** space respectively; $\mathbf{p}_{j}$ represents the j-th row of the matrix $P$

$W \in \Re^{6985 \times 10}$ where $6985$ and $10$ represent number of test instances and number of classes respectively; $w_{i,j}$ represents the probability that i-th test instance belongs to j-th class.

$D_{t} \in \Re^{4096 \times 85}$ where where $4096$ and $85$ represent number dimensionality of the feature space and dimensionality of the semantic space respectively.

$\lambda_{2}$ is a regularization parameter.

**Numbers in short:**

1. $6985$: Number of instances
2. $4096$: Dimensionality of the feature space
3. $85$:   Dimensionality of the semantic space
4. $10$:   Number of classes

Screenshot of the paper where optimization procedure is being discussed: -

[image: Optimization procedure]

Comment: Please explain your notation: crucially, which symbols represent the intended arguments of the function and which ones are intended to be parameters or constants?  On the face of it, this is a *quartic* (not quadratic) function.

Comment: @whuber, I have edited the question to explain all the symbols. kindly have a look

Comment: Thank you -- but you still need to supply the most crucial piece of information: *what are the arguments of the function??*  As written, *it is not a quadratic function.*  Thus, you must be conceiving of some of your terms as varying (the arguments) and others as not (the constants or parameters).  Which is which?

Comment: @whuber, In the above optimization function, argmin is on the variable Yt. with yi being individual rows of Yt

Comment: @whuber all other terms other than Yt (and hence yi) are constants

Comment: In that case what is the sense of "combined," since the second term does not appear to depend on $Y_t$ at all??

Comment: @whuber, the second term is related to the first term, for instance, the yi term actually refers to individual rows of the matrix Yt (used in the first term). For your reference, I am adding the snippet from the research paper so that you may relate easily (see updated question where I have added the screen shot from the paper itself)

Comment: I have updated my question so that authors are quoted verbatim